# I have a Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined exception when I am trying to get service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined exception when I am trying to get service from controller class.So I have a controller like this:

```html
package com.finartz.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.finartz.beans.UsersBean;

@Controller
public class UserController {
 
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/userList",method={RequestMethod.GET})
 @ResponseBody  //for to get answer in JSON format !
 public List< UsersBean > listUsers(){ 
  List < UsersBean > users = new ArrayList<UsersBean>();
  
  UsersBean user = new UsersBean();
  user.setName("Süleyman");
  user.setPhone("0545 542 17 00");
  
  users.add(user);
  
  UsersBean user2 = new UsersBean();
  user2.setName("Zeynep");
  user2.setPhone("0545 500 17 00");
  
  users.add(user2);
  
  return users;
 }
}
```

and I have a javascript file like this:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#showUsersButton").click(function(){
  showUsers();
 });
});

function showUsers(){
 
 $.ajax({
    url: "/finartzOdev/userList",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function() {
   
   var table = "";
   
   //we say class='table' to bootstrap !
   table += "<table class='table'>";
   table += "<thead>";
   table += "<tr>";
   
   table += "<th>" + "Name" + "</th>";
   table += "<th>" + "Phone" + "</th>";
   table += "</tr>";
   table += "</thead>";
   
   
   // I get the exception here !.
   response.forEach(function(users){
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td>" + user.name + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + user.phone + "</td>";
   });
   
   table += "<table>"; 
   
   $(".userListDiv").html(table)
   
   
  });
}
```

When ı am trying to get user informations from 
service at this line : response.forEach(function(users) I get the exception.

Comment: iterating 'users' but using object as 'user'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to receive the `response` in your Ajax  `done()` function to use it

```
}).done(function( response) {

            var table = "";

            //we say class='table' to bootstrap !
            table += "<table class='table'>";
            table += "<thead>";
            table += "<tr>";

            table += "<th>" + "Name" + "</th>";
            table += "<th>" + "Phone" + "</th>";
            table += "</tr>";
            table += "</thead>";


            // I get the exception here !.
            response.forEach(function(users){
                table += "<tr>";
                table += "<td>" + user.name + "</td>";
                table += "<td>" + user.phone + "</td>";
            });

            table += "<table>"; 

            $(".userListDiv").html(table)


        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much,Dont know how ı miss it :)

Comment: and ı changed users to user by the way